# Bolstering the security of a new system built on a legacy database

Tags: security, passwords, hash

We have an old legacy ASP application that stored customer passwords as salted MD5 hashes. We've written a new application in ASP.NET MVC to replace this.

I'd like to bump the protection of the password field up a notch and use SHA1 hashing. Obviously I need to do this without forcing customers to renew their passwords to create a new SHA1 hash.

My thoughts were to hash the existing MD5 hashes using SHA1. It means I'd still need to hash with MD5 and then hash again with SHA1 when customers logon and when they reset passwords but I can live with that.

Can anyone spot any flaws in this method? To me it seems like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using SHA1 you should use Bcrypt or something like it.

But otherwise your scheme seems reasonable. Luckily the existing hashes have a easy format to identify, so you can add a identifier prefix if you don't want to add a new column to the database.

I'd suggest altering the code to be able to handle md5, md5+bcrypt or bcrypt, then you can run a background process to upgrade passwords from md5 to md5+bcrypt, while the online login code upgrades to bcrypt?

Comment: Thanks Douglas. BCrypt certainly whets my appetite.

Answer (score 1):

1. Widen the column to support the hash
2. Introduce a second column to determine the hash strategy (or see below); default to MD5 (since that's the current hash)
3. Alter the login (and similar) and password change/reset routines to detect which hash strategy is in use based on this value and then apply it; if the value is hashed with a "deprecated" hash, then silently upgrade it (since you'll have the password in plain text from the user once you've verified it)
4. After some reasonable time period, consider locking out users who haven't upgraded old password hashes

You *can* auto-detect some hashing strategies, e.g. straight MD5 versus SHA1, based on the length of their encoded output - hex-encoded MD5 occupies 32 bytes, while SHA1 requires 40. However, the "hash strategy" can also incorporate information (meaningful to applications - make sure you document it thoroughly!) about any other operations performed on the hash, such as a salting mechanism, or the number of hash iterations, and is generally a little more robust. In the future, you might want to introduce a third hash (say Tiger-192) and repeat the upgrade process.

If you can't spare another column, then widen the existing one to support prefixing with some indicator of the hash, e.g. `{SHA1}xxxxxxxxxxxxx` - old hashes will not be prefixed, and can assumed to be MD5.

Comment: I'm trying to do this with minimal extra code (other than re-hashing with SHA1). The column is already fairly large (`varchar(1024)`) so no problems there. I also want to implement this upgrade for everyone immediately and I'd rather not wait for customers to login again to silently upgrade (that was a strategy I'd thought about as well). However your advice is very useful.